# how dependable/portable is _snprintf?

Tags: c++

how dependable is `_snprintf` from `stdio.h` - I mean what are the chances of it being missing?

Will it run on all compilers from the past 15 years? gcc 4.1+, VC++ 6, and all the compilers no one actually uses like borland and whatever...

I am writing a library with c++98 compatibility and was **AMAZED** that `snprintf` got introduced in c++11 - so recently. It just seems so essential for writing safe code - to protect against buffer overflows and yet - missing from c++98...

**EDIT:** I cannot afford 3rd party libraries or anything more than `stdio.h`

Comment: Not as dependable as things in `<iostream>`

Comment: @InnocentBystander I can only affort ```stdio.h```

Comment: Not quite what you asked, but I would never write code that used `sprintf`. I insist on using `snprintf`; if `snprintf` isn't available I'll happily use `_snprintf`, and if neither is available I'll either write my own or abandon that platform/compiler.

Comment: I faced the same question before and finally decided to write my own `snprintf`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `_snprintf` is not dependable. The following example fails to compile on Linux with gcc 4.9.3 and clang 3.6.2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int, char*[])
{
    char buffer[25];
    _snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "Hello world %d\n", 123);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: good enough for me... I tried it too >> [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ShtAnWU4tRzTk6qb) <<